# Moment.js isBefore function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My console log is giving me an unexpected output.

```
var bool = (moment("2017-04-08 23:00:00").isBefore(moment("2017-04-09 01:00:00", 'day')));
console.log(bool);
```

The output is false, for some reason.
According to the documentation, the following code should return true.

```
moment('2010-10-20').isBefore('2011-01-01', 'year')
```

Even if it's not a full year past, if it's a different year, my understanding is that it should return false. 
In my case, while it hasn't yet been 24 hours, it is a different day. 
Is there something I'm not understanding correctly?

Comment: Is `moment("2017-04-09 01:00:00", 'day')` a thing?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I believe it is: see https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before. I think the issue here is the presumed time zone. Those could well be the same day when normalized to utc or something. I'm just guessing though.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Like Aluan said, it is. It just states how granular the before test is.

Comment: @Marissa - There is no test in a call to `moment(...)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[@Oliver Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129570/oliver-charlesworth) is right, `moment()` doesn't accept `'day'` as a second argument. Have a look [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) and scroll down for all its valid signatures.

---

With that being said, you can either convert

```
isBefore(moment("2017-04-09 01:00:00", 'day'));
```

to

```
isBefore(moment('2017-04-09 01:00:00'), 'day');
```

or to

`isBefore('2017-04-09 01:00:00', 'day')`;

Both work.

---

[Here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) is the signature for isBefore.

Answer (score 5):

The `moment(...)` argument does *not* accept the 'day' parameter.

Instead, you should be calling `isBefore(...)` with the day parameter like so:

```
moment(...).isBefore(moment(...), 'day'));
```

More info can be found at the moment docs [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before).

Answer (score 0):

Similarly found the issue between chrome and safari browser, then I found that, the safari browser doesn’t validate properly when the date with timezone and microseconds value then I compare the date like below

```
"2021-05-11 22:00:23"
```

instead of using the date with microseconds and timezone

```
"2021-05-11 22:00:23.000 +0000"
```

then it works fine for me